# Top mounted heatsink for SMT part

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, heatsink

I'd like to use TI's DRV8432 motor controller (because it's the only >6A, integrated dual motor controller I can find). The trouble is, it requires a heatsink mounted on top of the IC. See this picture from [its datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8432.pdf)

[image]

I've never encountered a package like this before. I'm not sure how to find a mechanically compatible top-mount heatsink, or how it would be secured in place. So I need some design guidance for heatsinks like that.

I've noticed adhesive-backed heatsinks online, but I'm not sure if those are the standard way to solve the problem or if there's something better. (I'm baking the PCBs myself in a toaster oven, so I'm not constrained by manufacturing concerns, though I would like to know the manufacturable way to solve this.) I'd appreciate any help or links.

Comment: Their [eval board for that part](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slou291a/slou291a.pdf) is probably a good place to start for how to mount a heat-sink.

Comment: That picture looks like it has a ledge that could be clipped onto. Never saw an IC package like that before, though. Interesting.

Comment: In general, the heat sink is screwed to the PCB immediately to the edges of the part.

Comment: Follow Connor Wolf's link, and you'll get both layout and parts list which will let you provide a compatible heat sink. Also remember to get some thermal compound.

Comment: I bet the EVAL part number from the mfg "HEAVY METAL" is either TI's machine shop or a Rock band

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the fast advice. But I've actually been furiously googling for the eval board's "HeatSink_DRV-EVM_35Wx80Lx38T-40P" by manufacturer "Heavy Metal", and can't find anything. That manufacturer doesn't seem to exist. Connor, screwing the heatsink to the PCB sounds good; what is that type of heatsink called? (Digikey has a heatsink category called "bolt-on" but the selection is pretty limited.)

Comment: I think I was right.. it's the "rockers" in TI's machine shop

Comment: Contact TI and ask about the heatsink. Always contact the vendors about stuff like this. The whole purpose of eval kits is to assist sales. They don't know if you are in your garage or are part of a company. They will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone. TI got back to me on their forum:
https://e2e.ti.com/support/applications/motor_drivers/f/38/t/486539

Basically they recommend using Arctic Silver 5 Thermal Epoxy to glue down a generic extruded-aluminum heatsink such as this:
http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/AAVID%20THERMALLOY/652453B01299G.pdf

plus metal spacers to give the GND -> heatsink connection that is recommended by the DRV8432 datasheet.

For completeness: based on my internet search, it looks like the other heatsink options are:

2) Find a heatsink designed to clip to that specific package (those don't seem to exist for TI's unusual HSSOP package, but they're available for more standard packages.)

3) Buy a heatsink that mounts to holes in the PCB, using some sort of clip or spring-loaded push pins. Those seem to be around $40 apiece.

Comment: Alpha provide pin based heatsinks with thermal interfaces and push-pin mounting clips.
https://www.alphanovatech.com

Answer (score 4):

- 1st is the datasheet calls it a HTSSOP chip
- 2nd google HTSSOP
- 3rd find all the heatsinks others are using

e.g. https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers/audio_amplifiers/f/6/t/338242
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Dell used this sink for their Pentiums (custom) 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but for the DRV8432, it calls the package HSSOP not HTSSOP. I haven't been able to find other people heatsinking the HSSOP package. It looks like your pictures are of adhesive-backed heatsinks, which I could probably use, but this is for a moving robot so I'd prefer a more positive mechanical attachment.

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong -- are there heatsinks like this that can be reflow soldered to the top of the device? If so that would be easy.

Comment: sorry I just found that from my TI link Heatsink for TPA3116D2 HTSSOP package

Comment: not likely reflowed to a heatsink but my link shows the reference to the soldered clips shown in photo

Comment: HTSSOP = (Heat-Sink TSSOP). it is not an HSSOP